# Is there a way to do it faster?

Tags: python, python-2.7

ladder have around 15000 elements, this code snippet performed in 5-8sec, is there any way to do it faster? I try do it without checking for duplicate and without creating accs list and time was down to 2-3sec, but I don't need duplicate in csv file.
I work in python 2.7.9

```py
accs =[]
with codecs.open('test.csv','w', encoding="UTF-8") as out:
        row = ''
        for element in ladder:
                if element['account']['name'] not in accs:
                        accs.append(element['account']['name'])
                        row += element['account']['name']
                        if 'twitch' in element['account']:
                                row +=  "," + element['account']['twitch']['name'] + ","
                        else:
                                row += ",,"
                        row += str(element['account']['challenges']['total']) + "\n"
        out.write(row)
```

Comment: Instead of list, try using dictionary. That should make it faster. Membership check will be done in about O(1).

Comment: If the items are hashable (eg strings) then `accs = set()` and then `accs.add` instead of `accs.append` should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
seen    = set()
results = []

for user in ladder:
    acc  = user['account']
    name = acc['name']
    if name not in seen:
        seen.add(name)
        twitch_name = acc['twitch']['name'] if "twitch" in acc else ''
        challenges  = acc['challenges']['total']
        results.append("%s,%s,%d" % (name, twitch_name, challenges))

with codecs.open('test.csv','w', encoding="UTF-8") as out:
    out.write("\n".join(results))
```

Comment: It's need little change because ladder['account']['twitch'] is optional and not always set, but after that is the fastest solution. Now it takes below 0.2sec :OOOO Thanks You! Even in my dreams I did't think that it is possible to do this so fast

Comment: @XnIcRaM: that's what `if twitch in acc else ''` is for ;-)

Comment: with this form I get error. I change it to `if 'twitch' in acc:
                        twitch_name = acc['twitch']['name']
                else:
                        twitch_name = ''` and now it's ok

Comment: D'oh! `twitch` should have been `"twitch"` (fixed now). With this change, the inline `if` works fine.

Comment: It's works and I get time from 0.11 - 0.13 Amazing! Once again Thanks You so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can’t do much about the loop, since you need to go through every element in `ladder` after all. However, you can improve this membership test:

```
if element['account']['name'] not in accs:
```

Since `accs` is a list, this will essentially loop through all items of `accs` and check if the name is in there. And you loop for every element in `ladder`, so this can easily become very inefficient.

Instead, use a *set* instead of a list for `accs` as this will give you a constant membership lookup. So you reduce your algorithm from a quadratic complexity to a linear complexity. For that, just use `accs = set()` and change your code to use `accs.add()` instead of `append`.

Another issue is that you are doing string concatenation. Every time you do `someString + "something"` you are throwing away that string object and create a new one. This can become inefficient for a high number of operations too. Instead, use a list here to collect all the elements you want to write, and then join them:

```
row = []
row.append(element['account']['name'])
if 'twitch' in element['account']:
    row.append(element['account']['twitch']['name'])
else:
    row.append('')
row.append(str(element['account']['challenges']['total']))

out.write(','.join(row))
out.write('\n')
```

Alternatively, since you are writing to a file anyway, you could just call `out.write` multiple times with each string part.

Finally, you could also look into the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module if you are interested in writing out CSV data.

Comment: Big thanks, It's work great, now it take below 0.5sec, simple change, amazing effect :D  I first try csv module but I have problem with utf8 and then I leave it